# Efficient way to get data from mysql in a php foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql

I have some options stored in mysql.
The table contains 4 columns that look like this:

```
option_id | option_name | option_default | option_user_value
------------------------------------------------------------
1         | timezone    | Europe/Athens  |
2         | mode        | 1              |
3         | email       | test@test.test |
```

So far I get that info from the db using something like the following php code:

```
$table  = 'options';
$values = '
    option_name,
    option_default,
    option_user_value
';
$where = null;
$options = get_db_entries($table, $values, $where);

if ($options)
{
    foreach ($options as $db_entry)
    {
        if ($db_entry['option_name'] == 'timezone')
        { $_timezone = $db_entry['option_default']; }

        if ($db_entry['option_name'] == 'mode')
        { $_mode = $db_entry['option_default']; }

        if ($db_entry['option_name'] == 'email')
        { $_email = $db_entry['option_default']; }
    }
}
```

Is there a more efficient way in order to avoid those 'if' statements there in the loop ?
I mean is there a way to directly insert that info from those columns to each variable without IFs ?

Just out of curiosity, please check my `get_db_entries()` function too if you want.
I am still learning (not familiar with OO yet) and thanks in advance.
Have a nice day.

```
function get_db_entries($table, $values, $where)
{
    $db_host = '........';
    $db_name = '........';
    $db_user = '........';
    $db_pass = '........';
    //  -----------------------------------------------------
    $dbh = new PDO(
        'mysql:host='.$db_host.'; dbname='.$db_name,
        $db_user,
        $db_pass,
        array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8")
    );
    //  -----------------------------------------------------
    if ($where) { $where = ' WHERE '.$where; }

    $sql = 'SELECT '.$values.' FROM '.$table.$where;
    $results = $dbh->query($sql);
    //  -----------------------------------------------------
    $results_array = array();
    foreach ($results as $db_entry)
    { array_push($results_array, $db_entry); }

    return $results_array;
}
```

Comment: Don't recreate your database handle each time you make a database query.  And instead of `if - then`ing your loop to death, why not just throw the results of the table into an array?

Comment: what do you mean by "recreate your database handle" ? how do I do this mistake if you could explain please ? Also, if you check the function, it is already returning an array (check near the end).

Comment: See cpattersonv1's answer for what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you call that function with the DB connection you're opening, querying and closing the connection to the database... this causes a lot of overhead on the SQL server and the PHP/MySQL connector. You can run the server out of resources if there are a lot of queries. Pull it into an array so you only use one DB connection and one query like this:

```
<?php
$sql = "select * from database.table;";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while ($db_entry = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

    if ($db_entry['option_name'] == 'timezone')
    { $_timezone = $db_entry['option_default']; }

    if ($db_entry['option_name'] == 'mode')
    { $_mode = $db_entry['option_default']; }

    if ($db_entry['option_name'] == 'email')
    { $_email = $db_entry['option_default']; }

}
?>
```

Example with PDO (Not tested):

```
<?php
try {
$DBH = new PDO("mssql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname, $user, $pass");    
}
catch(PDOException $e) {  
   echo $e->getMessage();  
}  

$STH = $DBH->query('select * from database.table');

$STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ); 

while($row = $STH->fetch()) {

    switch($row->option_name){
    case 'mode':
    $_mode = $row->option_default;
    break;
    case 'email':
    $_email = $row->option_default;
    break;
    case 'timezone':
    //timezone
    $_timezone = $row->option_default;
    default:
    //do something else
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: Thanks I understand, but can I do this using PDO ? I made a function for it so that I use less code each time etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use an array, called `$option_defaults` for example, instead of your individual variables (`$_timezone`, `$_mode`, `$_email` etc.) and add entries to it using `$db_entry['option_name']` as a key with `$db_entry['option_default']` as the associated value.

Comment: Good idea. Although `$options` is already an array and I thought there is a better way to get the data directly from that array than mine above. Right now I am trying your solution.